# Can I create a taxonomy term that mirrors the name of a new custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

As part of a much broader problem I'm trying to tackle, I am wondering if I can automatically create a taxonomy term with the same name as a new post of a specific CPT.

The idea would be as follows. I'd have a cartoon-series CPT. When I create a new cartoon series post, a taxonomy term for the cartoon-series taxonomy would be created with the same name as this new post. Along with that top-level term, two sub-terms would be created: "Episodes" and "Special Features"

So, for each new cartoon series post I create, I'd get a total of three terms added. One with the same name as the post and two under that, that would always be the same for all cartoon series.

A few potential problems I foresee right away:
Can I have terms in a taxonomy that are exactly the same? Like Episodes appearing multiple times as sub-terms.
Can a taxonomy have the same name as a CPT? Ideally, both would be named cartoon-series.  The slugs for the sub-terms would need to be the same as I'd be displaying them in the url.

```
GOOD domain/cartoon-series/<series-name1>/episodes/<episode-name>   
GOOD domain/cartoon-series/<series-name2>/episodes/<episode-name>  
BAD  domain/cartoon-series/<series-name2>/episodes-1/<episode-name>
```

"episodes" would need to be the same slug even though they are not the same term. I'm not sure if this is possible even if they are under different top-level terms.

All of this is in effort to solve this problem:
[Need help with complex custom post type setup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183415/need-help-with-complex-custom-post-type-setup)

I'm all ears if you have any other ideas!

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Quick comment. You don't want your term name to be your post_name or post_title. Why? Because the post name and title can change and your taxonomy term could break. 

Instead use the post_id as the term name. Then for the rewrite rules and frontend displays uses the term name to find the post name or title.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar situation. While I can't currently remember the source, the code below will create a new entry into your taxonomy of choice, it could serve as the base for your needs.

```
// Automatically creates a category in the case log and adds it to the post.    
function add_title_as_category( $postid ) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    
    $post = get_post($postid);

    if ( $post->post_type == 'case') { // change 'post' to any cpt you want to target
        $term = get_term_by('slug', $post->post_name, 'case-log');

        if ( empty($term) ) {
            $add = wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'case-log', array('slug'=> $post->post_name) );
            if ( is_array($add) && isset($add['term_id']) ) {
                 wp_set_object_terms($postid, $add['term_id'], 'case-log', true );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'add_title_as_category');
```

Comment: Have you run into any problems with terms having the same slug?

Comment: Thus far I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Shadow Taxonomy Lib

https://github.com/mrbobbybryant/shadow-taxonomy

This looks like a robust solution for this issue and including wp cli support for creating, deleting, and evaluating the linkages.

I haven't test it yet but it seems like the perfect solution for this issue.